# Closeable element on a webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to embed a newsletter signup in the middle of my article page, whereby the visitor can close the signup box or sign up. Here are examples from another website that I'd like to implement on my webpage:

Example of signup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/417ti.jpg

Example of after signup:
https://imgur.com/a/KfNEC

I already have a signup embed code from my ESP, but not sure how to create a closeable element where I could insert the emebed code.

Comment: Can you define "closeable element"

Comment: Can you post your embed code?

Comment: Can you explain more details. like which framework or cms you are using? or it's just a HTML webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div, and put the signup embed code inside it. Then, add a button element to close the signup box. Add an event listener to the button, so that it sets `display: none` on the element when the button is clicked.

Example:

```js
const signupContainer = document.querySelector('#signupContainer')
const closeSignup = document.querySelector('#closeSignup')
closeSignup.addEventListener('click', () => signupContainer.style.display = 'none')
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #AAA;
}

.container button#closeSignup {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="signupContainer" class="container">
  <button id="closeSignup">X</button>
  embed code here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With javascript and jquery and css at your disposal, there's plenty of ways to get it done. As a novice programmer, here's how I'd do it:

1. Create a div in your webpage and give it an ID.
2. Inside the div, insert your desired content
3. Inside the X element, set onclick to go to a function
4. In your javascript function, get that div by its ID name and change the CSS property display to none. If you want to be a little fancier, you can lookup animate in Jquery. It looks a little like this:

   ```
       $("#IDname").animate({
           'height': '0px' //change the css height to 0
       },900, function(){  //900 miliseconds duration of animation
            //something to do after animating
       });
   ```